# How can i get List of users from Azure AD?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory

I am using asp.net core MVC and i want to read users from the Azure AD. I have read a lot in microsoft documentation and i know i have to used GraphAPI to do that, but i have no clue how. Right now everything is confusing to me.

I dont know where to place the code, i dont know where to get the authPRovider given in the GraphServiceClient. I dont even know what is that authprovider at all?!
Can anyone could give info and demo code so that i can actually understand how to do it would be appreciated! :) All the help is appreciated!

Comment: You can see the official sample: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create("application id")
                .WithTenantId("tenant id")
                .WithClientSecret("application secret")
                .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
            var result = graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
            foreach (var item in result.Result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.DisplayName);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

***UPDATE***

1.https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-aspnet-core

You can download this project directly

2.https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-aspnet-core/tree/master/demo

This is the documentation required to establish the above.

3.The screenshot below is an example of me.This asp.net core mvc project using microsoft graph is feasible.

[image]

This is an example of a page-only lists ad users.Just put the following access token in  ***var accessToken="your access token*********"***;and you can run it.

```
<html>

    <style>
        .userItem {
          background-color:lightgrey; 
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
        
        .userItem p {
          display: inline-block;
          width:25%
        }

        .LicenseItem {
          background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          height: 45%;
          overflow: auto;
        }
        
        .LicenseItem p {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 20%;
      
        }
     

        .loadMore {
            background-color: aqua;
            font-style: italic; 
            text-align: center; 
            padding: 15px;
        }
        </style>

    <body>
        <div id="message"></div>
        <div id="userListView">
            <div class="userItem" style="background-color: aqua;font-style: italic;">
                <hr>
                <p> user display name </p>
                <p> user email address </p>
                <p> user principal name </p>  
            </div>
            <div id="userList"></div>
            <div id="loadMore" class="loadmore"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var accessToken="your access token*********";
        var ItemView = " <div id='@id' class='userItem'><hr><p id='@id-obj' style='display:none'>@obj</p><p > @displayName </p><p > @mail </p><p > @upn </p></div>"
        function initPage(){
            $("#loadMore").empty();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=10',
                type: 'get',
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": 'application/json', 
                    "Authorization":"Bearer " + accessToken
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var userlist = data.value;
                    var nextpageUrl = data['@odata.nextLink'];
                    if(nextpageUrl){
                        $("#loadMore").append("<div onclick='loadMore(\""+ nextpageUrl  +" \")'>load more...</div>");
                    }
                    userlist.forEach(element => {
                        var view = ItemView.replace(/@id/g,element.id).replace("@displayName",element.displayName).replace("@mail",element.mail).replace("@upn",element.userPrincipalName).replace("@obj",JSON.stringify(element));
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(element));

                        $("#userList").append(view);
                    });
                },
                error:function(data){
                    var response = JSON.parse(data.responseText)
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="ERROR:" + response.error.message;
                }
            });
        }

        function loadMore(url){

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'get',
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": 'application/json', 
                    "Authorization":"Bearer " + accessToken
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var userlist = data.value;
                    var nextpageUrl = data['@odata.nextLink'];
                    
                    if(nextpageUrl){
                        $("#loadMore").empty();
                        $("#loadMore").append("<div onclick='loadMore(\""+ nextpageUrl  +" \")'>load more...</div>");
                    }
                    userlist.forEach(element => {
                        var view = ItemView.replace(/@id/g,element.id).replace("@displayName",element.displayName).replace("@mail",element.mail).replace("@upn",element.userPrincipalName).replace("@obj",JSON.stringify(element));
                        $("#userList").append(view);
                    });
                },
                error:function(data){
                    var response = JSON.parse(data.responseText)
                    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="ERROR:" + response.error.message;
                }
            });
        }
        initPage();

    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: when using ClientCredentialProvider it gives error on parameter   "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.confidentialClientApplication' "

I am really thankfull tho, also if you could make a simple explation of what we doing here would be great :)

Comment: @RicardoFigueiredoR hi, i'm sorry, this is a console c# program, it can list ad users, but your request is asp.net core mvc... I'm trying to make it happen....

Comment: Yeah, I tried that in console app and it worked tho... But what i actually need is in Asp.net core MVC, i have been reading a lot and i have to regist my application in azure right i think and i already did, but after that is getting complicated somehow

Comment: @RicardoFigueiredo hi,This is an example of using Microsoft graph to call the calendar view but not listing ad users, for asp.net core mvc I am not very familiar so spent a lot of time.If you find it useful, you can accept it as the answer, thank you very much.You can also refer to this.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet-core

Comment: Will it be able to get all users or only the top 999 users because there is a limitation of getting users using graph API ?