# How to aggregate multiple Azure AD users data with data from backend?

Tags: .net, api, rest, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am developing new application (.NET Core backend + React frontend) and I want to integrate Azure AD to do auth things inside my organization tenant.

Some models has the "author" property containing Object ID from access token (like in typical scenario with "user" table). Now, the main problem is that we will need to display at least first name + last name of the "author" on multiple views containing list of resource but on the backend, we have only "AuthorID".

How should I handle that kind of "aggregation" with azure ad? Should I somehow synchronize that specific user which is needed (like on resource creating) to local "users" table? Maybe call the user by ID on frontend with MS Graph?

Any advice would be very helpful.

Nothing at all, just looking for some advices.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you are asking about getting the first name + last name of author/user in the access token?

Comment: Not really, maybe one more example will better explain my needs.
Imagine that we have a form, where Azure AD users are in a dropdown and we can choose one of them, in the POST there will be one property, let's say "AuthorID" which is "ObjectID" from Azure AD users, then, after the resource has been created, I want to do simple GET by id to retrieve that, but also with "join" by ObjectID and return a few more user claims from Azure AD, is that example a little bit better?

Comment: And that also applies to list of the resource, think about join with Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

> Using Microsoft Graph Explorer, you can call the user by ID and can
> display multiple attributes. By using the below query,

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

[image]

To know more in detail, refer [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

> Using PowerShell, you can call the user by ID and can display multiple
> attributes. By using the below command,

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID "xxxxxxxx" | Select-Object ObjectId, GivenName,Surname,UserType
```

[image]

To know more in detail, refer [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0#example-2--get-a-user-by-id)

For multiple users you can loop through each user by getting list of users required.

Ref1 : [Get list of users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172767/getting-particular-user-details-from-azuread-using-powershell-cmdlets-in-c-sharp)

Ref2 : [Get list of users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64023983/how-can-i-get-list-of-users-from-azure-ad)

Also Refer : https://www.codeproject.com/tips/991663/displaying-user-full-name-instead-of-user-email-in